# Is $(\neg \exists m) (c_m < 0)$ correct way to express "There doesn't exist an $m$ that satisfies $c_m < 0$"

Tags: notation

I have seen this two successive parenthesis notation in several books but I am still not sure if it is a correct way to express such a non-existence. I also couldn't be sure  $\neg \exists$ is the correct way to express "there doesn't exist". Would love to hear ideas on how to express this in a better way, especially if the way I wrote is wrong.

Comment: It's ok. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Your way is correct but you could also write it as, $\forall m, c_m\geq 0$

Comment: It’s fine. I personally prefer $\neg\exists m\,(c_m<0)$, and you’ll also see $\neg(\exists M)\,c_m<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly fine and correct.

Perhaps the more natural way to put the parentheses would be
$$
\lnot (\exists m \;:\; c_m < 0).
$$
that is, the not ($\lnot$) has the outermost scope, and modifies the entire sentence, not just the $\exists$. But I do not think the above is very common in practice.

As has also been pointed out, you can simplify it by writing
$$
\forall m  \; : \; c_m \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Although I do see it occasionally, I consider that use of the colon non-standard.